How to design properly a membership history accross multiple groups?
I'm looking to design an application (Python with sqlite) which deals with some contributors moving across several groups through time.
My design looks currently like (PK in bold weight, FK in italic, both if a FK is part of the PK):

Group(Id, Name)
Contributor(Id, Name, FirstName)
Action(ActionId, Name)
ContributorAction (ContributorId, ActionId, Date)
Membership (GroupId, ContributorId, StartDate, EndDate)

My aim is to keep an history of memberships in order to retrieve the right membership group of a contributor at the time of a given contribution.
Doing that involve the use of date columns in a primary key (Membership table). However, EndDate could be NULL for the current membership of a contributor, and I read this could be not a good (or even permitted) practice.
Did I miss something here to get at least 3NF design?


However, EndDate could be NULL for the current membership of a contributor, and I read this could be not a good (or even permitted) practice.

There is no normalization issue here.
Sometimes people use an arbitrary large date instead of a NULL but that comes with its own problems.

I could also use epoch date for this field but I'd rather opt for a more meaningful solution... :-/

Using NULL for the EndDate is the more correct solution.  In reporting systems it's sometimes disfavored because it complicates the SQL to see who is active on a particular date.
